# Link Change In Relation To Time

Tags: javascript, html

Im building a button that is supposed to go to different links depending on the current time. Do you know why it doesn't seem to be working?

Here's the code:

```js
let href = 'https://google.com';
let dayElement = document.getElementById('dayElement')
let hr = document.getElementById('hr');
let min = document.getElementById('min');
let sec = document.getElementById("sec");

let d = new Date();
let day = d.getDay();
let ndate = d.toLocaleString();

switch (day) {
  case 0:
    day = "Sunday";
    break;

  case 1:
    day = "Monday";
    break;

  case 2:
    day = "Tuesday";
    break;

  case 3:
    day = "Wednesday";
    break;
  case 4:
    day = "Thursday";
    break;
  case 5:
    day = "Friday";
    break;
  case 6:
    day = "Saturday";
    break;
}

dayElement.innerHTML = day;

setInterval(() => {
  let currentTime = new Date();

  hr.innerHTML = formatTime(currentTime.getHours());
  min.innerHTML = formatTime(currentTime.getMinutes());
  sec.innerHTML = formatTime(currentTime.getSeconds());

}, 1000);

function formatTime(time) {
  return time < 10 ? "0" + time : time;
}

function changeLink() {
  let currentTime = new Date();
  let hour = currentTime.getHours();

  if (day === 1 && hour >= 0 && hour < 12) {
    href = 'https://www.google.com';
  } else if (day === 6 && hour >= 0 && hour < 12) {
    href = 'https://www.cnn.com';
  } else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 18) {
    href = 'https://www.youtube.com';
  } else if (hour >= 18 && hour < 24) {
    href = 'https://www.facebook.com';
  }

  window.location.href = href;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.hero {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
}

button {
  background-color: #18f98f;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.clock {
  font-size: small;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="itr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> link </title>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="changeLink()">Go To Link</button>

  <div class="hero">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="clock">
        <span id="dayElement">Monday</span>
        <span id="hr">00</span>
        <span>:</span>
        <span id="min">00</span>
        <span>:</span>
        <span id="sec">00</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the links to change with the change in time, but it didn't seem to work, you can try using different time spans with the code if you prefer

Comment: Your code appears to work fine for me, both using the current date and also forcing the values to those within the ranges in your `if` condition. Please add much more clear detail about what you believe is not working.

Comment: Why do `hr`, `min` and `sec` get updated in your interval - but `day` never does? Is it _not_ supposed to switch to the next day, when it passes `23:59:59`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you, were you able to get the button to change to all the four links with the code?

Comment: @CBroe That's the time that is displayed on the bottom right, the days don't need to be updated because of the switch function earlier atleast from what I understand, do you think they do? Thank you for your comment and Im thankful for your opinions too

Comment: _"the days don't need to be updated, do you think they do?"_ - well you tell us, how should we know? You are checking `day === X` in several of your conditions there, so I would assume that they _do_ matter? If it was Sunday, 23:59:59, and now the time ticks over to Monday, 00:00:00 - then the time portion would match in this condition `if (day === 1 && hour >= 0 && hour < 12)`, but the day would not - because it _should_ now be `1`, but you left it at the value it had on Sunday, `0`. You tell us, whether that is how is _should_ work, or not?

Comment: @CBroe from my understanding the [switch(day)] function should cover this? And RoryMcCrossan said that it works for him, so now im quite curious...

Comment: That is not a "function", but a control flow construct. And your code only goes through this switch statement _once_, when the page loads. `day` doesn't get any other, _updated_ value assigned anywhere else later on.

Comment: @cBroe so what would be the solution

Comment: @CBroe just to be sure , did you see the ```dayElement.innerHTML = day``` part?

Comment: Yes, and same as the preceding switch statement, that executes exactly _one single time_.

Comment: @cBroe so what would be the solution?

Comment: Move the code that sets `day` inside the interval function.

Comment: @Barmar how do you mean? Do you mind writing the code?

Comment: @Barmar would it be possible to change the code for the time intervals so it reflects the change in timezones i.e. GMT,EST,PST and so on

Comment: @barmar and also how would you go about changing the intervals from hours to hours and minutes i.e. 18>= && <24 to 18:30>= && 19:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code that updates `day` and fills in `dayElement` inside the `setInterval()` function, so it gets updated when the day changes.

You also shouldn't use the same variable `day` for the numeric and string version of the day.

```js
let href = 'https://google.com';
let dayElement = document.getElementById('dayElement')
let hr = document.getElementById('hr');
let min = document.getElementById('min');
let sec = document.getElementById("sec");

let day;

setInterval(() => {
  let currentTime = new Date();

  hr.innerHTML = formatTime(currentTime.getHours());
  min.innerHTML = formatTime(currentTime.getMinutes());
  sec.innerHTML = formatTime(currentTime.getSeconds());
  day = currentTime.getDay();

  switch (day) {
    case 0:
      dayElement.innerHTML = "Sunday";
      break;
    case 1:
      dayElement.innerHTML = "Monday";
      break;
    case 2:
      dayElement.innerHTML = "Tuesday";
      break;
    case 3:
      dayElement.innerHTML = "Wednesday";
      break;
    case 4:
      dayElement.innerHTML = "Thursday";
      break;  
    case 5:
      dayElement.innerHTML = "Friday";
      break;
    case 6:
      dayElement.innerHTML = "Saturday";
      break;
  }
}, 1000);

function formatTime(time) {
  return time < 10 ? "0" + time : time;
}

function changeLink() {
  let currentTime = new Date();
  let hour = currentTime.getHours();

  if (day === 1 && hour >= 0 && hour < 12) {
    href = 'https://www.google.com';
  } else if (day === 6 && hour >= 0 && hour < 12) {
    href = 'https://www.cnn.com';
  } else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 18) {
    href = 'https://www.youtube.com';
  } else if (hour >= 18 && hour < 24) {
    href = 'https://www.facebook.com';
  }

  window.location.href = href;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.hero {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
}

button {
  background-color: #18f98f;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.clock {
  font-size: small;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="itr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> link </title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="changeLink()">Go To Link</button>

  <div class="hero">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="clock">
        <span id="dayElement">Monday</span>
        <span id="hr">00</span>
        <span>:</span>
        <span id="min">00</span>
        <span>:</span>
        <span id="sec">00</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```